# DialogBox not drawing the dialog correctly

Tags: winapi, win32gui

So I have the following dialogbox template which I saved in a .rc file:

```
DIALOG_TEST DIALOG 0, 0, 186, 95
STYLE DS_3DLOOK | DS_CENTER | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_SHELLFONT | WS_CAPTION | WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Dialog"
FONT 8, "Ms Shell Dlg"
{
    PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel", IDD_CAN, 129, 24, 50, 14, 0, WS_EX_LEFT
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK", IDD_OK, 129, 7, 50, 14, 0, WS_EX_LEFT
}
```

which I call using [DialogBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-dialogboxa) in the following way:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    HWND button;
    switch (message)                  /* handle the messages */
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            button = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "BUTTON",
                                     "Test",
                                     WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
                                     200, 40, 200, 30,
                                     hwnd, (HMENU) 1, NULL, NULL);
            break;

        case WM_COMMAND:
           switch(LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                case 1:
                    DialogBox(GetModuleHandle(NULL), TEXT("DIALOG_TEST"),
                              hwnd, AboutDlgProc);
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage (0);       /* send a WM_QUIT to the message queue */
            break;
        default:                      /* for messages that we don't deal with */
            return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

All works fine except that for some reason the window is not being drawn correctly:

[image]

it's like the dialogbox is being drawn twice, what am I doing wrong?

As for the Window Procedure for the dialogbox, the only thing it does is close the window when the "Cancel" is pressed.

```
    BOOL CALLBACK AboutDlgProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message,
    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

   switch (message)
    {

     case WM_COMMAND:

        switch(HIWORD(wParam))
        {

            case BN_CLICKED:

                switch (LOWORD (wParam))
                {
                    case IDD_CAN:
                    EndDialog(hDlg, TRUE);
                    return TRUE ;
                }

                break;
        }

        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dialog boxes do not use standard window procedures and should not call `DefWindowProc`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/dlgbox-programming-considerations.

Comment: Side note: Please avoid using IDE's (like Code::Blocks) that default to ANSI encoding. No one uses ANSI encoding in 2019 (unless they are maintaining legacy code).

Comment: @JonathanPotter I'm not calling DefWindowProc, I've updated my question with the window procedure for the dialogbox. The *DefWindowProc* is for the MAIN window, not the dialogbox

Comment: @JonathanPotter Fake code? what the heck do you mean. the only thing I've' ommited is the WinMain function, which is irrelevant for this problem. If it bothers you so much to answer the question, then you should stop wasting your time posting replies like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A button can send more than one kind of notification in a WM_COMMAND message, so if you want to create the dialog box only when the button is clicked you need to check to make sure that the notification code (in `HIWORD(wParam)`) is [BN_CLICKED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/bn-clicked). See [WM_COMMAND documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-command).

Comment: I did include an additional switch case for BN_CLICKED inside WM_COMMAND and the dialogbox still has that wrong appearance.

Comment: @trey why don't you update your question so I can see what you did?

Comment: Hi Stuart, just did that

Comment: @trey You added the check for BN_CLICKED in AboutDlgProc which is correct, but you also need to add it to WindowProcedure. After that, you also need to change AboutDlgProc as follows: 1 Return FALSE for the messages it doesn't process, and 2 process the WM_INITDIALOG message (you can process this message by returning TRUE).

Comment: that worked perfectly, thank you. I thought it wasn't necessary to process BN_CLICKED since you add an menu id when you create the button, processing that ID during WM_COMMAND would be enough, but apparently it isn't